# C# Load XML with special characters inside node

Tags: c#, xml

We receive an xml string from an external API, and one element has a bunch of GT/LT signs.

When we run this code, it fails:

```
var xml = @"<SomeNode>10040:<->10110:<->10130:<->10150:<->10160:<->10180:<->10330:Value=><->10330:Matching=><->10330:Value2=><->10330:Value3=><->10330:Value4=><->10447:<->10418:No<->10419:No<->10430:No
</SomeNode>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

//System.Xml.XmlException: 'Name cannot begin with the '-' character, hexadecimal value 0x2D
```

I looked into escaping those characters, but as far as I can tell there isn't a way to escape only the ones inside SomeNode.

So I know that I could run some kind of string replacement using a regex or something to clear that out. But, is there an elegant way to solve this using existing XML related tools?

Comment: Here's the thing. That **isn't xml**. No xml parser will like it. Ideally, you need to yell at whoever provided this data, and tell them to kindly give you xml. For that to be xml, it should presumably be `<SomeNode>10040:&lt;-&gt;10110:&lt;-&gt;101...` etc.

Comment: Thanks @Marc Gravell, I was afraid that might be the case..

Comment: You could perhaps try using `xml = xml.Replace("<->", "&lt;-&gt;");` as a hack?

Comment: Note that if the authors are lazy (and they are, as they didn't bother to use an XML library) see if they'll just be kind enough to wrap element contents in `<![CDATA[ ]]>`, which is cheap to do even if your generator is lame. The only string not allowed in that is `]]>`, but that's seldom an issue. You *can* do that yourself in a post-processing step, but only by kludgy string matching and assuming things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, there isn't an xml tools solution, and so it'll be a custom string replacement solution.